# Трудности с кастомизацией типов python

Tags: python

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, сделал кастомный тип для работы с данными, прилагаю код

```
class uint16_t:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.bit_size = 16
        super().__init__(value)
        
class int32_t:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.bit_size = 32
        super().__init__(value)

class Foo:
    '''Базовый класс.'''

class Bar(Foo):
    first: uint32_t
    second: uint16_t
```

Пример вызова

```
obj = Bar(first=10, second=5)
```

при проверке типов получаю:

```
type(obj.first) - <class 'int'>, должен быть <class 'uint32_t'>
type(obj.second) - <class 'int'>, должен быть <class 'uint16_t'>
```

Что нужно добавить чтобы эта фигня заработала?

Answer (score 3):

Забыли инициализировать с помощью класса:

```py
obj = Bar(first=uint32_t(10), second=uint16_t(5))
```

Comment: А возможно ли отредактиовать класс так, чтобы подтавляемые данные сами конвертировались в требуемый тип?

Comment: Задавайте новый вопрос